# android 4.1 - 4.4 system_alert_window permission

Tags: android, permissions, system-alert-window

Although my practice is google play,
I can get System_alert_windows permission on Android 5+ OS But system_alert_window is not allowed between 4.1 and 5.0.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information

Answer (score 1):

```
Dialog   dialog = new Dialog(LoginActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
            thank_you.setContentView(R.layout.forgotpwd);
            thank_you.show();
```

Use dialog using these syntax then there will not be need of system_alert_window permission.

Comment: But I am developing a lock application of my own, error while running